# C - 2D Array sscanf and indexing error

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to parse through a text document and put data from each line into a 2-D array of char strings. However, after the file closes, each row of my 2-D array is a copy of the last row of data. It's as if the last row overwrites all of the previous data. For example, array[0][1] prints the same value as array[19][1], even though array[0][1] should be a different value.

C Code:

```
int h = 0;
const char* array[20][5];
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
{
        sscanf(line,"%s%*[^\n]",firstWord);

        if (strcmp("transition",firstWord) == 0)
        {
                sscanf(line,"%s%s%s%s%s%s",garbage,temp0,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4);
                array[h][0] = temp0;
                array[h][1] = temp1;
                array[h][2] = temp2;
                array[h][3] = temp3;
                array[h][4] = temp4;

                h++;

        }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Text Document Sample:

```
transition  0   1   3       1       R   
transition  3   0   4       0       R   
transition  1   _   7       _       R   
transition  0   _   5       _       R   
transition  0   0   1       x       R   
transition  1   1   2       x       L   
transition  2   0   2       0       L   
transition  2   1   2       1       L   
transition  2   x   2       x       L   
transition  4   0   4       0       L   
transition  4   1   4       1       L   
transition  4   _   4       _       L   
transition  4   x   4       x       L   
transition  1   0   1       0       R   
transition  1   x   1       x       R   
transition  3   1   3       1       R   
transition  0   x   0       x       R   
transition  7   _   7       _       R   
transition  2   _   0       _       R   
transition  3   _   6       _       R
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not copying the contents and you overwrite the `tempN` pointers on every iteration.

Here

```
array[h][0] = temp0;
```

for every value of `h` you store a pointer to `temp0` and you overwrite `temp0` with the next `scanf()`.

So when you dereference `array[h][0]` it points to `temp0` whose contents are those scanned by `scanf()` in the last iteration.

You also skip checking whether `scanf()` succeeded and that means that you might try to print or copy uninitialized values, if you do so your program will invoke undefined behavior and you will be in hell trying to debug that.

Try to copy the content instead

```
array[h][0] = strdup(temp0);
```

or the equivalent function if you are not on a *POSIX* compliant system.

**EDIT**: to clarify what [this comment says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685632/c-2d-array-sscanf-and-indexing-error/32685665?noredirect=1#comment53216127_32685665), you should never do that! If you want to implement your own `strdup()` the correct way would be

```
char *strdup(const char *const input)
{
    char *result;
    size_t length;
    length = strlen(input);
    result = malloc(length + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(result, input, length + 1);
    return result;
}
```

To make it safer you could check `input == NULL`, but the standard implementation of `strdup()` does not check so that would be your addition to it.

- Why to do it like this?

Simple, `strlen()` computes the length of the string by iterating through the characters of the string until the `'\0'` terminating `nul` byte is found and `strcpy()` will also copy characters from `input` to `result` iterating until `'\0'` is found, instead `memcpy()` is generally optimized to copy faster and you can use `memcpy()` because you know the length of the string, you needed it anyway to allocate space for the result.

In short, calling `strlen()` followed by `strcpy()` is not a smart thing to do, of you know the length there is no need to compute it again.

Comment: You can use `array[h][0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp0) + 1)); strcpy(array[h][0], temp0);` if you don't like `strdup`.

Comment: No, you should never use `sizeof(char)` because it's guaranteed by the standard to be `1`. And you **must** check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL`. And most importantly, is there any reason to avoid `strdup()`? Suppose that it does exactly that, `malloc()` -> check for `NULL` and return `NULL` in that case, copy the data. And your copy isn't really as efficient because you will compute the length of the string twice.